# No previous prototype for function BOOL areIntsDifferent (int thing1, int thing2 ) and NSString * boolString (BOOL yesNo)

Tags: objective-c

I get this code from a book but i could not get it work. What is my problem here? As the title says

"No previous prototype for function BOOL areIntsDifferent (int thing1, int thing2 ) and NSString * boolString (BOOL yesNo)"

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

BOOL areIntsDifferent (int thing1, int thing2 ) {
    if ( thing1 == thing2) {
        return (NO);
    }
    else {
        return (YES);
    }
}    

NSString * boolString (BOOL yesNo) {
    if (yesNo== NO) {
        return (@"NO");
    }
    else {
        return (@"YES");
    }    
} 

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    BOOL aretheydiffrent;
    aretheydiffrent = areIntsDifferent (5,5);
    NSLog(@"are %d and %d diffrent? %@", 5, 5, boolString(aretheydiffrent));
    aretheydiffrent = areIntsDifferent(23,42);
    NSLog(@"are %d and %d diffrent? %@", 23, 42, boolString(aretheydiffrent));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message translates to:

> This means that GCC found a global function definition without seeing
>   a prototype for the function. If a function is used in more than one
>   file, there should be a prototype for it in a header file somewhere.
>   This keeps functions and their uses from getting out of sync

Making the functions `static` should sort this out:

```
#import < Foundation/Foundation.h >

static BOOL areIntsDifferent (int thing1, int thing2 )
{
     return thing1 != thing2;
}

static NSString * boolString (BOOL yesNo)
{
    return yesNo ? @"YES" : @"NO";

}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])

{
   BOOL aretheydiffrent;

   aretheydiffrent = areIntsDifferent (5,5);

   NSLog(@"are %d and %d diffrent? %@",
      5, 5, boolString(aretheydiffrent));

   aretheydiffrent = areIntsDifferent(23,42);

   NSLog(@"are %d and %d diffrent? %@",
      23, 42, boolString(aretheydiffrent));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is it that I run the exact same code the OP posted (without the `static` definitions) in Xcode 4.3 and it worked flawlessly?

Comment: Different compiler?  The OP doesn't state which one he's using.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon XCode 4.3 uses CLang, not GCC

Comment: why i need the static? and what does it do?? i don't understand.

Comment: Making it `static` means that it can't be used in more than one file and the warning should go away.  Have you tried it?

Comment: yes. It worked. I am learning it. But the book do not have the static, in front of the functions. Another question, how do i know, when i need to use static?

Comment: If you won't be using the function outside of the file it's defined in, then you can use `static`. If you want to use the function everywhere in your program then you you'll need to provide a declaration in a header file so the other files know the function prototype.

Comment: Adding `static` may have fixed the problem, but is beyond the scope of the example from your book. Read my answer for a more thorough explanation without use of `static`.

Answer (score 1):

First we should not use static, secondly we should not use '==' in objective c(oc), when we use bool, because in oc, numbers are written  in
internal storage like this 0000 0000, so '5' read as0000 00021, and '23'read as '0001 0111' '42'
in oc, computer could think 23 as 5, which is wrong.
For the same reason we shouldn't use == yes

Here is an example:

```
NSLog(@"%d  %d",YES,NO);
if(areIntsDifferent_faulty(23, 5)==YES)
{
   NSLog(@"Are %d and %d different? %d YES",23,5,areIntsDifferent_faulty(23, 5));
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Are %d and %d different? %d NO",23,5,areIntsDifferent_faulty(23, 5));
}

if(areIntsDifferent_faulty(23, 5))
{
    NSLog(@"Are %d and %d different? %d YES",23,5,areIntsDifferent_faulty(23, 5));
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Are %d and %d different? %d NO",23,5,areIntsDifferent_faulty(23, 5));
}
```

Output:
are 5 and 5 different? no
are 23and 42 different？ yes
1 0
are 23 and 5 different? 18 no
are 23 and 5 different? 18 yes

so write like this :if(areIntsDiffreent_faulty(23,5))this is right!

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean? agree with you that static is not necessary, but use == in objective-c is correct for BOOL comparison.

Answer (score 0):

A function prototype is essentially the "signature" of the function: what is its name, what does it return, what are its arguments, etc. A function body is what the function actually does, and is what's contained between the braces of a function.

**Prototype:**

```
BOOL areIntsDifferent(int thing1, int thing2);
```

**Body:**

```
BOOL areIntsDifferent(int thing1, int thing2)
{
    return (thing1 != thing2);
}
```

You are most likely receiving just a compilation warning, rather than an error (warnings just tell you something and your program might still work, errors actually stop the show). Function prototypes are very useful in larger projects, and are typically contained in a separate file called the header. I don't know which book you have, but you'll probably read more about this later on.

There are two possible fixes:

- Add the following lines to the top of the file, after `#import ...`

  `BOOL areIntsDifferent(int thing1, int thing2);`
  `NSString* boolString(BOOL yesNo);`
- Turn off the "Missing Function Prototypes" warning in your Xcode project config settings.

The first fix is actually adding the function prototypes to the top of file, which satisfies the warning. The second fix is actually disabling the warning so the compiler won't bring it up.

The first fix is something like "I hear you, thanks for reminding me, Mr. Compiler." The second fix is something like "Shut up compiler, I'm a big boy and have my functions right where I want them!"

Comment: The book title is Learn Objective-C on the Mac. Publisher Apress.

Comment: Yes I imagine they will probably introduce you to header files later on. Header files are a way for you to tell other people what functions you have available (by only giving them the prototypes), but keeping the function body to yourself (to protect how your super secret function works, etc.) For now, either add the prototype to the top of the file, or disable the warning :)

Comment: I do understand the concept of functions in c++. and I gave some thought of it. Now is clear to me. Thank you! @inspecto g.

Comment: but i am not good in classes in any language. Still I am confuse with the header files and the .h thing. Glad you guys can help me!.